# 'hgroup' is not a known element error in Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I'm getting this error on using the  tag in the
*.component.html, however on removing the  element the code works fine, what is the reason behind it? Uncaught Error: Template
 parse errors: 'hgroup' is not a known element:

> 1. If 'hgroup' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acording to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup)

> The  element has been removed from the HTML5 (W3C) specification, but it still is in the WHATWG version of HTML. It is partially implemented in most browsers, ...

So I suggest you remove `hgroup` element from your html code and use CSS to achieve same styling as you might get different styling in different browsers.

You should also checkout [Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines without using `<hgroup>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements)

Comment: "The element has been removed from the HTML5 (W3C) specification, but it still is in the WHATWG version of HTML. It is partially implemented in most browsers, ..." is not present anymore on the MDN webpage and `hgroup` seems to be very much a stable tag. I believe this answer needs updating.

Answer (score 2):

@Dhyey's answer is outdated, and as @David Riccitelli mentioned - `hgroup` *is* actually part of the living HTML standard. This was [fixed](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/48b354a83e6d94735a03eebb3a52c5698e7a0f44) in Angular 15, and the `hgroup` element is now supported in Angular.